# Is there a way of creating such button when clicked, then pops up another buttons on top of it in flutter?

Tags: flutter

[Button Overlay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7x6i.png)

I am trying to create a button that will show other buttons when clicked.
Please click on the link above to see a snapshot of what I mean.

Comment: please show what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

use [flutter_fab_dialer](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_fab_dialer) package

**example**

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  //Provides an image of a cat
  static String getNewCatUrl() {
     return 'http://thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=src&type=jpg&size=small'
         '#${new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}';
   }

   int _counter = 0;

  //Adds value to counter
   void _incrementCounter() {
     setState(() {
       _counter++;
     });
   }

   //Prints the value of the counter
   void _logCounter() {
     setState(() {
       print(_counter);
     });
   }

  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {

     ImageProvider img = new NetworkImage(getNewCatUrl());

    //The list of FabMiniMenuItems that we are going to use
     var _fabMiniMenuItemList = [
       new FabMiniMenuItem.withTextWithImage(
         img,
         4.0,
         "Button menu",
         _logCounter,
         "Click me",
         Colors.blue,
         Colors.white,
         true
       ),

       new FabMiniMenuItem.withText(
         new Icon(Icons.add),
         Colors.blue,
         4.0,
         "Button menu",
         _incrementCounter,
         "Click me",
         Colors.blue,
         Colors.white,
         true
       ),
       new FabMiniMenuItem.noText(
         new Icon(Icons.add),
         Colors.blue,
         4.0,
         "Button menu",
         _logCounter,
         false
       ),

       new FabMiniMenuItem.noTextWithImage(
         img,
         4.0,
         "Button menu",
         _incrementCounter,
         false
       )
     ];

     return new Scaffold(
       appBar: new AppBar(
         title: new Text(widget.title),
       ),
       //Using a Stack will assure that the Dialer will appear at the end of your layout
       body:  new Stack(
         children: <Widget>[
           new Center(
             child: new Column(
               children: <Widget>[
                 new Text('You have pushed the button this many times:'),
                 new Text('$_counter', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1),
               ],
             ),
           ),
           new FabDialer(_fabMiniMenuItemList, Colors.blue, new Icon(Icons.add)),
         ],
       ),
     );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[flutter_speed_dial](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_speed_dial) will do what you are asking.

Simply provide the FloatingActionButton parameter of a Scaffold with a SpeedDial widget from the package above. Here's a snippet below.

```
                   floatingActionButton: SpeedDial(
                      animatedIcon: AnimatedIcons.menu_close,
                      backgroundColor: primaryColor,
                      elevation: 5,
                      overlayOpacity: 0,
                      children: [
                        SpeedDialChild(
                          child: Icon(Icons.add),
                          backgroundColor: primaryColor,
                          label: 'Meal Set',
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.push(context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NewSet()));
                          },
                        ),
                        SpeedDialChild(
                          child: Icon(Icons.add),
                          backgroundColor: primaryColor,
                          label: 'Single Meal',
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                          onTap: () {
                            addNewMeal();
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
```